# Pidgin for XMPP -- SSL Handshake failed

Tags: ssl, pidgin, xmpp, ubuntu-18.04

I installed the latest Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to connect to our in-house XMPP server (which is quite old and I have no access to) with Pidgin like I used to.

But I'm unable to connect... Getting an `SSL Handshake Failed` error.

This is what I get in the debug window:

`(10:37:11) account: Connecting to account d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3.
(10:37:11) connection: Connecting. gc = 0x55e3f7cdca10
(10:37:11) dnsquery: Performing DNS lookup for %%SERVER_IP%%
(10:37:11) dnsquery: IP resolved for %%SERVER_IP%%
(10:37:11) proxy: Attempting connection to %%SERVER_IP%%
(10:37:11) proxy: Connecting to %%SERVER_IP%%:5222 with no proxy
(10:37:11) proxy: Connection in progress
(10:37:11) proxy: Connecting to %%SERVER_IP%%:5222.
(10:37:11) proxy: Connected to %%SERVER_IP%%:5222.
(10:37:11) jabber: Sending (d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3): <?xml version='1.0' ?>
(10:37:11) jabber: Sending (d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3): <stream:stream to='%%SERVER_NAME%%' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(10:37:11) jabber: Recv (177): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="%%SERVER_NAME%%" id="a1c57c52" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
(10:37:11) jabber: Recv (486): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
(10:37:11) jabber: Sending (d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(10:37:11) jabber: Recv (50): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
(10:37:11) nss: Handshake failed  (-12279)
(10:37:11) connection: Connection error on 0x55e3f7cdca10 (reason: 5 description: SSL Handshake Failed)
(10:37:11) account: Disconnecting account d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3 (0x55e3f700e310)
(10:37:11) connection: Disconnecting connection 0x55e3f7cdca10
(10:37:11) connection: Destroying connection 0x55e3f7cdca10
(10:37:12) util: Writing file prefs.xml to directory /home/dgoosens/.purple
(10:37:12) util: Writing file /home/dgoosens/.purple/prefs.xml`

*(replaced SERVER_NAME and SERVER_IP)*

Tried every possible account setting... but nothing seems to work...

Any suggestions ?

---

**EDIT (2018-05-07)**

So it appears my server uses an expired STARTTLS certificate.
I followed the instrcutions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/610585/force-pidgin-to-acept-an-invalid-certificate

Downloaded the certificate with `openssl` and imported into Pidgin...
But this does not change anything... still getting the same debug information.
So I'm guessing I fail to configure the app properly

Any suggestions how to deal with this ?

Comment: So you have configured the client to use a TLS certificate.  Is the server using that same certificate?  What ciphers did you enable when you created that self-signed certificate.  You should edit your question, to include this vital information, so your question can be answered.

Comment: did not set up any TLS certificate... and as far as I can see, there is no way to do so in Pidgin. Just requested "encryption if available" and I'm pretty sure there isn't any. Also, with the same setup in Thunderbird, or Psi (another XMPP client) it's working alright...

Comment: You might not have configured it, but does not change the fact your current configuration, is set to use a TLS certificate based on the contents of the xml document, specifically this: *xmpp-tls*

Comment: thanks @Ramhound updated my question with the info I managed to gather... but afraid that this does not help you

Comment: @dGo it sounds like the XMPP server is not well maintained. My guess it that it may be more than the certificate, but possibly related to the SSL versions the server supports. Newer operating systems such as Ubuntu 18.04 will not use insecure versions of the protocol, which could explain your problem. To conclusively determine if this is the problem, it looks like a packet capture from Wireshark would be required (the log message from Pidgin is not detailed enough to give the reason for the handshake failure).

Comment: Oh I know for a fact that it is not well maintained.... Unless someone can tell me how to configure Pidgin to run without encryption, I think I'll just stick to Thunderbird to use it for the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The debug message `(10:37:11) nss: Handshake failed  (-12279)` is key here.   From https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html this refers to:

> SSL_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION -12279  "Peer using unsupported version of security protocol."
>
> On a client socket, this means the remote server has attempted to negotiate the use of a version of SSL that is not supported by the NSS library, probably an invalid version number. On a server socket, this means the remote client has requested the use of a version of SSL older than version 2.

Try using the NSS Preferences plugin (from the Buddy List, Tools->Plugins) to change your minimum TLS/SSL version to something low enough that the server supports.

Comment: thanks... I already set that to 1.0 and checked all ciphers on... starting to think it is not pidgin that causes this but the underlaying open_ssl python implementation...

Answer (score -1):

Pidgin requires you to setup certificate on the server. For example using ejabberd, you must edit the ejabberd.yml and add the `certfile` option

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "c:/ejabberdserver/server_new.pem"
```